# How to programatically instantly close and open popup in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, jquery-events

## General

I want to have a tutorial implemented in one popup for my webpage. For it to visually look like multiple popups it has to appear, disappear and change content. Conceptually that is

```
("#thePopup").popup("close").html(myContent).popup("open")
```

but it's not working because `.popup("close")` usually executes after `.popup("open")`. I came up with a workaround working code as seen below , but that doesn't have a popup `history` functionality. Is there a way to make it work and also have `history` functionality? And for the understanding, why `history=false` is crucial for the following code to work?

## Code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxjdedq/3/))

HTML:

```
<div id="ppp" data-role="popup">
    <a href="#" id="btn" class="ui-btn">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#pppInfo").click( function() { 
    $("#ppp")
        .on( "popupafterclose", function( event, ui ) {
            $("#ppp")
                .off( "popupafterclose" )
                .popup( "open" );})
        .html("Other content")
        .popup( "option", "arrow", true ) // Do some formatting
        .popup( "close" );
});

// Uncomment to get a working workaround.
//$("#ppp").popup( "option", "history", false);
```

When `history=true`, in firefox with firebug I see not single but multiple events. First one triggers listener, but later ones close it again. Sometimes 2, sometimes 3 calls in a row. **Why?** In most of cases, late events close opened popup, if browser lags the popup can be seen for a milisec. Rarely and randomly (after refresh it may be "normal" again) some very weird things happen like all page gets wrapped in a popup.

## Related/Similar Questions

[Opening a popup window from another popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054205/opening-a-popup-window-from-another-popup)

[jQuery mobile popup is not closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206455/jquery-mobile-popup-is-not-closing)

[How can I open a second jquery-mobile popup from the first popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409895/how-can-i-open-a-second-jquery-mobile-popup-from-the-first-popup)

[Is it possible to open popup in popup(parent) in jquery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23355959/is-it-possible-to-open-popup-in-popupparent-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: You could add some delay: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/wrxjdedq/4/

Comment: @ezanker, thanks, I tested delay and it works but I see it as not a safe option if browser lags longer than delay. In my case disabled history is less worse than risky or very long delay.